# I need the blender 2.78a splash screen picture blend file

Tags: blend-files

Is it possible to get the file for the splash screen? If yes, then how do I get the blender model of the cover picture of version 2.78a. The guy with the high tech suit made on cgstrive.com. The picture is in the link below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splash screen file for 2.78 (and some previous splash screens) are available on the 'demo files' page on blender.org, here:

https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/